# how to dynamically change the property of a spring bean which is autowired?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

I have a solution for this question. But I am not positive it is the right thing. I have a bean created with a property that will change per request.
when I autowire this bean, I am manually calling the setter property
I think there is a better way to do this or even change the design

Here is the bean that I will be autowiring

```
@Component
  public class Handler1 {

    private final Channel inboundChannel;

   //1 public Handler1(Channel inboundChannel){
   //2   this.inboundChannel=in;
   //3 }

   public void setChannel(Channel in){
      this.inboundChannel=in;
   }
}
```

On my cleint side, I do

```
 @Component
   public class Client {

   @Autowired
   Handler1 myHandler;

   @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx){
        final Channel inboundChannel = ctx.channel(); //4
        handler.setChannel(inboundChannel);

        // Start the connection attempt.
        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        b.group(inboundChannel.eventLoop())
                .channel(ctx.channel().getClass())
                .handler(myHandler) 
                .option(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ, false);

                 .....
        }
```

First of, I cannot do constructor with parameters (line 1-3) since channel is not autowired. Secondly, I am calling setter to change the state of a bean which I am not is the right thing to do. Any other alternatives here?

Comment: *I have a bean created with a property that will change per request* Make that bean request scoped

Comment: yes, I am aware of that. but I would still have to call setter on that bean?

Comment: Idk what ChannelHandlerContext is nor why it cannot be done in @Bean factory method.